# Depicting Multi-Viscosity?

Tags: png

I have to create a small 150 x 150 pixel (give or take) vector image that depicts categories. I'm not really sure how to create an image that encapsulates the various thickness of liquids.

I was trying out a container pouring a liquid but the viscosity is the essential part of the image and showing multiple liquids and varying thickness (especially in a flat, three-color schemed icon) is difficult especially with the size constraints.

Comment: There must be a greater context that might inform your decisions

Answer (score 1):

Try 2 drops of liquid with longer and shorter lengths. The container is non esential.

Comment: You could add a picture. Right now your going to get the nag... we appreciate longer answers etc...

Answer (score 0):

For complex concepts that do no not readily lend themselves to symbols, sometimes text is the best method - i.e. write out "Viscosity" or use an abbreviation (Visc./Vis.). A possible symbol-based approach would be "teardrops" of varying lengths suggesting different liquids and their viscosity. You might also use an internet image search and see how others have attempted to solve this design problem.